# What is the recommended approach to implement admin-actions-alike functionality outside admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin-actions

I've been searching a way to reproduce admin-actions behavior on my own tables using django-tables2. I haven't found any module to introduce this functionality to a ListView to derive from it and looking at ModelAdmin I see there are many methods implied on this.
Of course, I can add a form around my table to get the checkboxes and a submit button pointing to a view that works with the ids but I'm looging to get a combo to choose among different actions as in django-admin but also to have that 'actions' meta option to list some methods as the possible actions to perform.
I found [django-actions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-actions/0.0.5) which is still very young but also it introduces it's own page for operations and I just need to integrate functionality on my own model so I can connect some input type=select with the model actions.
Any comment is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution for it. You have to implement your actions in your views and the functionality to your templates.

Add, edit and delete operations are very easy to implement in your `views.py`. This depends on your models, but you can trigger database manipulations from within your templates and keep the logic in your `views.py`.

You can also easily add a form to your templates as it is described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/):

```
# forms.py

from django.forms import ModelForm
from myapp.models import Article

# Create the form class.
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Article
         fields = ['pub_date', 'headline', 'content', 'reporter']
```

`model` := Choose your model which you want to modify / add
`fields` := Select some fields from your model, which you want to show up in your form

This defines a form corresponding to your model, which can be used in your templates to modify or add an entity to your database.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. This helps me know I should stop searching and start coding :-) I will post here my final results in case someone can use them.